# Enjoy or enjoying, come or are coming

Tags: present-tense

The sentences are from "English Grammar Practice" by L.G. Alexaner.

In this exercise according to the book's answer key only "are coming" and "are asking" are correct in #7 but both the present simple and continuous are correct in #9.

7. "People are always coming in and asking me to help them".

Isn't it also correct to say "People always come in and ask me to help them"?

In #9. "I am enjoying (or enjoy) the job and I am finding it very amusing.

If the person is currently enjoying her new job if this is a current situation most books say only "present progressive" works.
Sentence #9 the book says both are correct: "I am enjoying (or enjoy) the job and I am finding it very amusing."

In the same exercise it says "I am missing you" and "I miss you" are both correct but it doesn't say "find" is correct in "My colleagues are always finding things in books." The text is about a librarian and it describes strange things people use as bookmarks.

Comment: I don't know why you think *most books say only "present progressive" works* for your second example. Simple Present and Progressive are both perfectly okay (as is a mixture of both, in either sequence), and I'd be prepared to bet money (not that it could ever be definitively resolved) that Simple Present would be ***significantly more common***. Both verb forms are also fine for the first example, and any teaching aid that says different isn't worth your time and attention. It's almost always just a ***stylistic choice*** in such contexts.

Comment: Thank you. I aedited my question and added additional sentences from the same exercise.

Comment: I don't think *My colleagues are always finding things in books* is a good example to illustrate a ***very*** subtle distinction in this area. But compare Simple Present *My son **always finds** dirty pictures in my monthly copy of **National Geographic*** to the Continuous version *My son **is always finding...*** In that context, there's no doubt that the first one primarily asserts that ***he never fails to find any dirty pictures***, whereas the second one simply asserts that finding such dirty pictures is something he ***often*** does (but he might not find ***every*** dirty picture! :)

Comment: I didn't use the second "are" before "are asking" is it optional? If I have a list of actions as an example from the same book "The plumber is putting in a new bath, the electricians are rewiring the system, and the carpenter is building up some new shelves." Are they optional here too? I see that there is "is" and "are" perhaps when there is only singular or plural it's optional.

Comment: Do you mean in your example  "My son is always finding... In that context, there's no doubt that the first one primarily asserts that he never fails to find any dirty pictures" "finding" means "looking for"dirty pictures?

Comment: *to find* means *to **successfully** look for something*. It makes no difference whatsoever if you "delete" the "predictably repeated" subject + verb + adverb or not, in something like *People are always coming in and **people are always** asking me to help them* (well, it makes no difference to the *meaning* - but in practice we usually avoid pointlessly repeating so many obviously predictable words, so it's actually a bit "odd" to do so). In your "plumber + electricians + ..." context, they're different subjects so you have to say them, but you can in principle delete the verbs **are + is**

Comment: (It doesn't matter that ***are*** and ***is*** aren't exactly the same. It's enough that they're both just "tensed" forms of the verb TO BE.)

Comment: Regarding the second sentence. Yes, most books say it's a limited duration or something that is currently happening or a current trend. But thank you for letting me know. I thought only the present continuous works there. So even if we have a limited duration or want to show that something is currently happening, it's  a current trend both  tenses work. Am I right?  For example, "I am working in a bank." Temporarily. And "I  work in a bank." Again temporary action expressed by the present simple.

Comment: "People are living in poverty" current trend and the same idea with "People live in poverty"- temporarily.I don't understand what books mean by saying that a current trend/situation and a limited duration are different things.

Comment: The main difference is that if I say *I live in England*, it tends to imply I've *always* lived there (I'm describing a "timeless" state). But if I say *I am living in England* (a little unlikely without a time-based adverbial element such as ***currently***) that would very strongly imply ***I have also lived elsewhere*** (or perhaps simply that I expect to do so in the future).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Present Progressive to complain, to express annoyance or any other negative emotion/feeling.

> [Oh, these annoying] people are always coming in and asking me to help them. [I just can't focus on my work.]

Grammar exercises usually have hints to help you identify the correct tense. In this case, it's "always". Along with "continually", "constantly", it's used to stress a point.

> He is **constantly** leaving dirty clothes in the bathroom.

> He’s **always** hogging the computer.

The Present Simple sentence

> People always come in and ask me to help them.

is grammatically fine, but it carries a different meaning, as in describing your routine in the office, or your responsibilities. I also find "always" in there a bit unnatural.